# German linguistic requirements for an assistant professor (Juniorprofessur) in Germany

Tags: application, job, germany, language, assistant-professor

Officially, proficiency in the German language is not required for assistant professor positions. However, it is clear that the assistant professor is supposed to teach bachelor students (most probably in German). What are the unpublished requirements regarding language skills?

For someone with basic to intermediate level, is it worth applying for this position?

Comment: Why don't you ask the people advertising the position? The general answer would be "sometimes yes, sometimes no, it depends".

Comment: @Lewian No one will give you the correct answer in an email because they cannot say "No" as officially it is not required so the application will be definitely accepted in its form but the ranking of candidates is something different. I want to know how likely the members of the hiring committee will consider this.

Comment: As far as I know the German system (and I know a bit of it) it is illegal to make this a criterion if it isn't officially a criterion, in which case they should tell you. Unless you are sure you have the full official text, it can't hurt to ask them.

Comment: @Lewian I see your point but the committee will rank the candidates without giving any explanation. One can be ranked +3 because of one's skills in German without explicitly knowing the main factor given the number of factors to select the best candidates.

Comment: The private thoughts of individuals are pretty hard to regulate. But, I think that Germany is pretty serious about its stated standards. And if you want to live and work in Germany it is probably a good idea to plan to become fluent in German.

Comment: @Younes: They have to justify their decision internally though, with reference to the official criteria.

Comment: @Lewian The official criteria are usually fluffy enough to be bent in whatever way required to support the preferred candidate (assuming that the preferred candidate is at least a reasonable choice).